# internal ToMVCHmlString in TagBuilder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, tagbuilder

I am looking to write a few helpers in my own assembly modeled after the helpers in System.web.mvc.  My problem is that I cannot use the call to Tagbuilder.ToMvcHtlString since it is internal. So if I return a string it wont be ready for asp.net 4 when it comes.

I dont want to add anything to system.web.mvc as that is a given dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
```